# Python Regex extract paragraph text between number

Tags: python, regex

I have text as follows and I want to extract just the text

```
1. foobar

2. foo

3. bar
```

The result should be `[foobar, foo, bar]`.

What python regex will extract the results I want? I tried the following but no luck

`r'\d+.*?(?=\d|$)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can anchor the string, escape the dot and match optional spaces after it.
Then you can capture the rest of the current line, and then keep on matching all lines that do not start with the digits and dot.

To get the values, you can use re.findall which would return the value of the capture groups.

```
^\d+\.[^\S\n]*(.*(?:\n(?!\d+\.).*)*)
```

For just single lines:

```
^\d+\.[^\S\n]*(.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ouv9YI/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/pCdVtH)

If you don't want the trailing newlines, you could strip them:

```
import re

pattern = r"^\d+\.[^\S\n]*(.*(?:\n(?!\d+\.).*)*)"
s = ("1. foobar\n\n"
     "2. foo\n\n"
     "3. bar\ntest\n\n")

print([x.strip() for x in re.findall(pattern, s, re.M)])
```

Output

```
['foobar', 'foo', 'bar\ntest']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text="""1. foobar

2. foo
 
3. bar"""

matcher=re.compile(r'\d+\.\s+(\w+)')
result=matcher.findall(text)     # result is ['foobar', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Explanation from python documentation:
If there is exactly one capturing group in regular expression, the **findall** returns a list of strings matching that group.